SSAS MDX - Improve speed of slow SUM of IIF
I am trying to calculate a version of a preexisting measure where I am capping the value at a very granular level, and summing the capped values. The original data consists of a set of (hundreds of thousands) of applications for something, each of which has an ID and took some number of Hours to be processed. I'm just trying to cap the number of hours per application in order to better handle some outliers that are throwing downstream calculations out.
The query is very quick to run if I don't include the new "Hours Capped" measure, but if I do the time to run the query increases from seconds to 20 minutes+. Are there any changes I can make to the code below that might make it more efficient? In the real version I'm pulling in a few more dimensions and measures than this too. The structure of the model is hopefully pretty self-explanatory.
I should add that the vast majority of the Applications are for offices that I am excluding in the subselect - are they still contributing to performance?
WITH 
    MEMBER [Measures].[Hours Capped] AS 
        Sum(
            [Application].[Application Id].[Application Id].MEMBERS,
            Iif ([Hours] > 45, 45, [Hours]) 
        )
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY 
    {
        [Measures].[Application Count],
        [Measures].[Application Value],
        [Measures].[Hours],
        [Measures].[Hours Capped]
    } ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY 
    {
        (
            [Business].[Office].[Office].ALLMEMBERS,
            [Client].[Client Name].[Client Name].ALLMEMBERS,
            [Client].[Client Code].[Client Code].ALLMEMBERS,
            [Application].[Application Category].[Application Category].ALLMEMBERS,
            [Dates].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS 
        )
    } ON ROWS
FROM (
    SELECT (
        {
            [Business].[Office].[France],
            [Business].[Office].[Germany],
            [Business].[Office].[Italy],
            [Business].[Office].[Netherlands]
        } ) ON COLUMNS
    FROM [Application Data]
)

